# Hex Viewer in Java

Tags: java, binary, hex, readfile

I'm a beginner in java programming and i'm trying to create a hex viewer in java, my IDE is Netbeans. Below is the code.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import static java.lang.System.out;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class hope {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        JFileChooser open = new JFileChooser();
        open.showOpenDialog(null);
        File f = open.getSelectedFile();
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);

        int bytesCounter = 0;
        int value = 0;
        StringBuilder sbHex = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sbResult = new StringBuilder();

        while ((value = is.read()) != -1) {
            //convert to hex value with "X" formatter
            sbHex.append(String.format("%02X ", value));

            //if 16 bytes are read, reset the counter,
            //clear the StringBuilder for formatting purpose only.
            if (bytesCounter == 15) {
                sbResult.append(sbHex).append("\n");
                sbHex.setLength(0);
                bytesCounter = 0;
            } else {
                bytesCounter++;
            }
        }

        //if still got content
        if (bytesCounter != 0) {
            //add spaces more formatting purpose only
            for (; bytesCounter < 16; bytesCounter++) {
                //1 character 3 spaces
                sbHex.append("   ");
            }
            sbResult.append(sbHex).append("\n");
        }

        out.print(sbResult);
        is.close();
    }
}
```

The problem are:
1. It doesn't read the files fast enough"It takes a minute to read a file of 200kb"
2. It gives "Out of Memory" error when I tried a large file e.g. 80mb

What I want it to do:
1. Display all the hex code in seconds "Read and display hex of any size of file"
2. read file of any size without error code.

The Question:

What do I need to change or add in my code to achieve the above "What I want it to do"?

Comment: Check out this [example](http://www.gubatron.com/blog/2009/04/20/how-to-make-a-quick-dirty-hexviewer-updated/).

Comment: Thank you @DevilsHnd, I checked it out, but the code was created since 2009, which I think there are lots of improvement to do, and for what reason I couldn't make it to work, remember I'm newbie. Java codes without comments makes it hard for me to understand and edit.

Comment: Why not use only `out.print ()` , instead of `sbHex.append ()` and `sbResult.append ()` ? Maybe using StringBuilder is unnecessary ?

Comment: @gregn3 well I edited the code, and removed all unnecessary codes, but still nothing. Same speed and memory issue when tried to load a big file. **checkout this link, the Hex editor was created in java and read a file up to 9 exabytes.** (http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.github.javadev%22%20AND%20a%3A%22hexeditor%22). I just want to be able to view it, I don't want to edit the hex. So, how does the developer manage to open file of that size without memory leaking and how does it open fast?

Comment: @KingAmada I tried your original example on a 5.5 MB file. It took about 20 seconds to read and 20 seconds to print out the contents. I think that other app is not reading the entire file, only a small piece at a time. (Which is displayed on the screen I guess). You could try [RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) to read/write a file in small pieces. Use the `seek()` method to set the read position in the file...

Answer (score 1):

For this simple example, the key is to use "Buffered" input stream.
Change this line of code:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
```

to:

```
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream(f));
```

You will get a much better result.

(But to fix the Out of Memory error, you have to think about a different approach since currently you are "caching" all the data to one string which will eat all your memory. Maybe print/clear the string builder each time the counter reaches 15 or higher? You can try and let us know. :)

Comment: Thank you @YK S, I did what you advised, but still nothing improved. remember I'm newbie.

Comment: So I did a quick test using your code and a file (about 12M), got the timestamp printed before/after the while loop and here is the result:
Before (using InputStream): 59sec  After (using BufferedInputStream): 13 sec. (Sorry I just have to ask: did you re-compile your source code after you make the change? sometime the IDE just won't do it for you)

Comment: Thanks @YKS, I restarted the IDE and got same result as yours. Please checkout this link, the Hex editor was created in java and read a file up to 9 exabytes.(http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.github.javadev%22%20AND%20a%3A%22hexeditor%22) I just want to be able to view it, I don't want to edit the hex. So, how does the developer manage to open file of that size without memory leaking and how does it open fast? can you point me to part of his code that he used in implementing it so that I can use it in my own. I know I'm asking a lot, please help me out. Thank you again.

Comment: If you are reading the whole file byte by byte in a loop, you can't avoid the memory problem. Please try the method mentioned by gregn3, I think that's a good way to go.